# Release build depends on debug dll from MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

Our release build requires debug versions of MFC libs. Does anyone know where to start looking in the project so we can correctly change those dependencies to release ones?
Command line used:

> for %f in (*.lib) do dumpbin /IMPORTS:msvcrt120d.dll /OUT:output.txt

EDIT:

> And the output I get (irrelavant of what import file I specify):

```
Dump of file DataMts.lib

File Type: LIBRARY
```

`Summary`

```
     1B0 .CRT$XCU
    15BA .bss
     238 .data
    5D67 .data$r
    1FC0 .debug$S
   1ABB2 .drectve
   1AE68 .pdata
   1CA3C .rdata
    BDF0 .rdata$r
     730 .rsrc$01
    25F8 .rsrc$02
     636 .text$di
  146BCA .text$mn
    F259 .text$x
     597 .text$yd
   3BC58 .xdata
     980 .xdata$x
      10 ATL$__a
      10 ATL$__z
```

Comment: Check your MFC settings. If those are fine, then it's likely a dependency of one of the libraries you link against. Check to see if you're linking against a debug version of a (3rd party) library, that links against the debug version of the MFC.

Comment: @IInspectable Hi, great hearing from you buddy. It's likely a dependency of one of the libraries we link against. But the number of those libraries is huge (over 160) and I believe I'll have to go manually over them and do the check, unless you can suggest better solution?

Comment: You can automate the process: Run a [FOR](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx) loop over all DLLs and execute [DUMPBIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx) with the [/IMPORTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7k09ee7.aspx) option, passing one of the debug MFC DLLs as the optional *file* parameter.

Comment: @IInspectable, Hi, really appreciate your help. Would you be so kind and provide an example how to use this? Oh, and tiny clarification, those are not MFC dlls (as I've been told) but msvcrt120d.dll. One of our modules depends on it and I need to find our which one. Thank you.

Comment: Something like `FOR %f IN (*.exe *.dll) do dumpbin /IMPORTS:msvcrt120d.dll %f` should do. Best to pipe the output into a text file so that you can later search through it in a text editor. Searching for `msvcrt120d.dll` will take you directly to the modules you are looking for.

Comment: @IInspectable Hi, I've tried it and unfortunately, I don't think it works as intended, that is, it does execute, there is no problem with syntax, but the output is exactly the same no matter what /IMPORTS:file I specify. I provided the output into my OP as an edit, and I wonder if you can take a look at it and see if it makes any sense to you. Thank you

Comment: You left out the `%f` parameter to `DUMPBIN`. Is that a typo?

Comment: @IInspectable yes, thank you, you are the man!

Answer (score 0):

Just went through this to ensure our final build had no debug dependencies
Here is my bat file -

```
@echo off
echo Testing...

for %%v in (*.exe *.dll) do (
dumpbin /imports %%v | find /i "0d.dll" > nul
if not errorlevel 1 echo %%v is Debug
)
```